# Unable to add permissions to Linkedin app and getting error unauthorized_scope_error

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

I want to add LinkedIn loggin button to my site which is made with React.

Thus, I've created a new app on Linkedin and I have CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET. I've also added REDIRECT_URL. But in the PERMISSIONS section I see no permissions and I cannot add them.

[image]

And now when I try to do an API call to the url from the docs:

```
const url = `https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=${REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REACT_APP_REDIRECT_URI}&scope=r_emailaddress`
```

It doesn't work and I get `error=unauthorized_scope_error`

Any idea how to solve that?

I think that if I be able to add those permissions it would be solved.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On LinkedIn developer portal ,go to your app and In product tab select "Share on LinkedIn" and "Sign In With LinkedIn" product then you got following permissions.

r_liteprofile
r_emailaddress
w_member_social

Answer (score 0):

use this scope scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social